# Problem to install LibreOffice

Tags: 13.10, libreoffice, dpkg

When I install LibreOffice Appear

```
vitor@vitor:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i LibreOffice_4.2.2.1_Linux_x86_deb
dpkg-split: erro: erro lendo LibreOffice_4.2.2.1_Linux_x86_deb: É um diretório
dpkg: erro ao processar LibreOffice_4.2.2.1_Linux_x86_deb (--install):
 sub-processo dpkg-split retornou estado de saída de erro 2
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 LibreOffice_4.2.2.1_Linux_x86_deb
vitor@vitor:~/Downloads$
```

Why I can't install LibreOffice using dpkg?

Comment: Could you translate the output into English? I can't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to install directly from libreOffice rebositories

1. Add repo by `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa` Then press `Enter`
2. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade` Wait for completion and you should be good to go.

P.S, This is obviously assuming you have an earlier version already installed.

If not, skip second step and you should be able to find it already listed in Sofware Center

Alternatively, run `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`

Comment: In addition, if you run GNOME. Check <http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/libreoffice-42-released-with-new.html> for the new icon theme

Answer (score 1):

What I did if I remember correctly:

```
sudo su
#Enter your password
apt-get remove libreoffice*.*
apt-get autoremove
```

Download all dpkg files pack from libreoffice. I suggest to use beta/development version, but it is your choice.

```
#unzip it
#do 'cd' into a unziped folder
cd DEBS
```

you should be now in the folder where are all deb files, continue...

```
dpkg -i *
```

can you see libreoffice installed? :)

Comment: Are there problem if I use apt-get autoremove?

Comment: well, not sure if it removes anything actual. It removes packages which were automatically installed while installing an actual program but now no longer needed.

Even if you try this command you might not win anything, but you also won't loose anything! ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Better perform `sudo apt-get -f install` Just in case any dependencies got broken.
2. Re-download the file ; I prefer using `wget http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/4.2.2/deb/x86/LibreOffice_4.2.2_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz`
3. If download got interrupted, repeat last command adding `-c` As in `wget -c http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/4.2.2/deb/x86/LibreOffice_4.2.2_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz`
4. Upon completion, unzip the .tar.gz file and install again by `sudo dpkg -i LibreOffice_4.2.2_Linux_x86_deb`